# Xcode 10.3 failing to run on iOS 13 iPhone 6s - This iPhone 6s is running iOS 13.1, which may not be supported by this version of Xcode version 10.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, katalon-studio

Can somebody help me out to fix this issue. I have iPhone 6s [iOS: 13.1] and Xcode version 10.3 installed in my Mac book. Now I am unable to run the WebDriverAgent as it does not support the iOS version. 
So somebody who is using Xcode 11 or higher version can share the Device Supporting files from 13.0 & 13.1 folder.

Also I do not want to upgrade my Xcode version to 11 since I have few other iPhone devices which are not updated to iOS v13 and it works fine with current version Xcode 10.3. So Kindly help me out.

You can find these file inside the following path:- 
Go to Applications folder, right click on Xcode 11 icon → Show Package Contents, navigate to folder Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Thanks in Advance,
Revankar

Comment: Please [search on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=This%20is%20running%20which%20may%20not%20be%20supported%20by%20this%20version%20of%20Xcode%20version).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just download device support folders 13.0 & 13.1. https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport.
Then add them into yours, restart your Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

I download the Developer disk image for iOS 13.1 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.1.zip

Follow Those steps.

Unzipped downloaded file
Right click on Xcode and click on Show Package Content.
Then paste your file on path.

Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport
Then Restart Your Xcode.

It works for me.